# How to add image slices in place of createTextNode when building a table with JS

Tags: javascript

I have an external JavaScript file which builds a table of four rows and four columns and inserts the text "row 0, column 0", "row 0, column 1", "row 0, column 2" and so forth with the document.createTextNode. However, I want to insert image slices into the table cells instead of the text to build up a large image. Is there any ideas about to go about this, my JS code is below.

```
function generate_table(){
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  var tbl = document.createElement("table");
  var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");

  for (var r = 0; r < 4; r++){
    var row = document.createElement("tr");
    for (var c = 0; c < 4; c++){
      var cell = document.createElement("td");
      var cellText = document.createTextNode("row "+r+", column "+c);
      cell.appendChild(cellText);
      row.appendChild(cell);
    }
    tblBody.appendChild(row);
  }
  tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
  body.appendChild(tbl);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## 3D Array

Get the urls of 16 images and place them in a 3D array:

> ```
> var fourXfour3DArray = [
>   [url0, url1, url2, url3], 
>   [url4, url5, url6, url7], 
>   [url8, url9, url10, url11], 
>   [url12, url13, url14, url15]
> ];
> ```

In the demo the line where `createTextNode()` is replaced by a function called `setImg()` which will accept a 3D array of image urls, and index numbers of current row and column positions.

---

### Demo

**Details are commented in demo**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
</head>
<body>

<script>
var imgArray = [['http://www.clker.com/cliparts/U/k/6/3/4/M/yellow-rounded-number-0-md.png', 'http://www.clker.com/cliparts/2/5/6/d/1242796868203109724Number_1_in_green_rounded_square.svg.med.png', 'http://www.clker.com/cliparts/k/e/O/E/Y/f/orange-rounded-square-with-number-2-md.png','http://www.clker.com/cliparts/m/e/j/n/R/V/number-3-in-light-blue-rounded-square-md.png'],['http://www.clker.com/cliparts/X/b/l/a/X/w/red-rounded-square-with-number-3-md.png', 'http://www.clker.com/cliparts/p/7/W/8/F/T/purple-rounded-square-with-number-5-md.png', 'http://www.clker.com/cliparts/1/R/V/3/S/t/number-6-square-orange-md.png', 'http://www.clker.com/cliparts/g/I/c/I/S/3/red-rounded-square-with-number-7-md.png'], [ 'http://www.clker.com/cliparts/V/T/J/T/o/M/blue-rounded-square-with-number-8-md.png', 'http://www.clker.com/cliparts/B/f/Q/6/l/x/red-rounded-square-with-number-8-md.png', 'http://www.clker.com/cliparts/W/J/x/h/t/E/red-rounded-square-with-number-10-md.png', 'http://www.clker.com/cliparts/O/C/B/M/R/0/blue-rounded-square-with-number-11-md.png'], ['http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/Y/a/p/2/W/hot-pink-rounded-square-with-number-12-md.png','http://www.clker.com/cliparts/V/X/Y/5/Y/t/red-rounded-square-with-number-13-th.png', 'http://www.clker.com/cliparts/W/H/D/y/K/5/green-rounded-square-with-number-14-md.png', 'http://www.clker.com/cliparts/q/l/a/c/m/x/purple-rounded-square-with-number-15-md.png']];

function generateTable(imgArray){
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  var tbl = document.createElement("table");
  var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");

  for (var r = 0; r < 4; r++){
    var row = document.createElement("tr");
    for (var c = 0; c < 4; c++){
      var cell = document.createElement("td");
      // Call setImg() pass imgArray, current row and column index
      var cellImg = setImg(imgArray, r, c);
      cell.appendChild(cellImg);
      row.appendChild(cell);
    }
    tblBody.appendChild(row);
  }
  tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
  body.appendChild(tbl);
}

/*
Pass a 3D array, current index numbers of row and column positions
Create a <img>
Add url and width
return <img>
*/
function setImg(x3DArray, row, col) {
  var url = x3DArray[row][col];
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = url;
  img.style.width = '50px';
  return img;
}

generateTable(imgArray);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I ended up getting things working by changing the document.createTextNode to document.createElement and adding another line of code with the url cellText.setAttribute("src", "../images/slicedImages/_r"+(i+1)+"_c"+(j+1)+".jpg"); to get the images.

Comment: I see, customizing the filenames is a good solution that many people never consider or willing to do (either they don't own the original or lazy). Here's a more efficient version: `cellImg.src = \`../images/slicedImages/_r${i+1}_c${j+1}.jpg\`;`